# How can I solve the optimal solution of a system of overdetermined nonlinear equations using R

Tags: r, solver, nonlinear-functions

```r
library(BB)
library(nleqslv)
library(reprex)
library(ktsolve)

yfunc<-function(x){
   y<-vector()
   y[1]<-a+b*sin((238.61/365)+c)-(39393*0.00341802+149-273.15)
   y[2]<-a+b*sin((1821.2/365)+c)-(38795*0.00341802+149-273.15)
   y[3]<-a+b*sin((1946.8/365)+c)-(38875*0.00341802+149-273.15)
   y[4]<-a+b*sin((2072.4/365)+c)-(39231*0.00341802+149-273.15)
   y[5]<-a+b*sin((2111.36/365)+c)-(38505*0.00341802+149-273.15)
   y[6]<-a+b*sin((2223.12/3650)+c)-(37962*0.00341802+149-273.15)
   y
}
guess=list(a=8,b=15,c=30)
solv1<-ktsolve(yfunc,guess = guess)
#> Error in ktsolve(yfunc, guess = guess): Fewer guesses than equations.  System is underdefined.
```

I want to use multiple equations to find the optimal solution of a nonlinear equation. How should I configure the function?
<sup>Created on 2021-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use nonlinear least squares to find the parameter values that minimize the sum of the squares of the differences of the two sides of the the following model.  We use the `plinear` algorithm which only requires that we provide starting values for the parameters that enter non-linearly, in this case only `c`.  As there are two parameters that enter linearly, the right hand side should be a two column matrix which will be matrix multiplied by the vector of those parameters: `c(a, b)` .  No packages are used.

```
x <- c(238.61, 1821.2, 1946.8, 2072.4, 2111.36, 2223.12) / 365
y <- c(39393, 38795, 38875, 39231, 38505, 37962) * 0.00341802 + 149 - 273.15

fm <- nls(y ~ cbind(a = 1, b = sin(x + c)), start = list(c = 30), alg = "plinear"); fm
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: y ~ cbind(a = 1, b = sin(x + c))
##    data: parent.frame()
##      c .lin.a .lin.b 
## 30.255 12.226  4.598 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 10.72
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.47e-09
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have now followed your method to get the desired result

Comment: How to calculate if y becomes 6 matrices？

Comment: It depends on what the particulars are but you may be able to just unravel the matrices into long vectors..

Comment: When I combined 22 equations and wanted to solve 3 unknowns, the following error appeared, which has troubled me for a long time. How should I solve it?Error in qr.solve(QR.B, cc) :The'a' in the solve is a singular matrix

Answer (score 0):

You put six equations in `yfunc`.
If you want to guess `a`, `b`, and `c` and use `ktsolve`, reduce number of equations in `yfunc`.

AND length(guess)
must be same as the number of y[j] equations in yfunc, to avoid having an overor under-defined system. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ktsolve/ktsolve.pdf

For example,

```
yfunc<-function(x){
  y<-vector()
  y[1]<-a+b*sin((238.61/365)+c)-(39393*0.00341802+149-273.15)
  y[2]<-a+b*sin((1821.2/365)+c)-(38795*0.00341802+149-273.15)
  y[3]<-a+b*sin((1946.8/365)+c)-(38875*0.00341802+149-273.15)
  #y[4]<-a+b*sin((2072.4/365)+c)-(39231*0.00341802+149-273.15)
  #y[5]<-a+b*sin((2111.36/365)+c)-(38505*0.00341802+149-273.15)
  #y[6]<-a+b*sin((2223.12/3650)+c)-(37962*0.00341802+149-273.15)
  y
}

guess=list(a=8,b=15, c= 10)
solv1<-ktsolve(yfunc, guess = guess)
```

returns

```
  Successful convergence.
solution is:
        a         b         c 
 9.521837  1.238768 12.817678
```

Comment: If I want to use the idea of ​​optimization to calculate the optimal solution of the system of equations, what should I do, because there may be many similar tasks in subsequent work

Comment: @yiboliu Is those subsequent works are like set of three equations? For example, {(E1,E2,E3), (E4,E5,E6),....}.

Comment: The follow-up work should be based on a set of months and a year, about a set of 20 equations, solving 3 unknowns, so an optimization algorithm may be needed to better approximate the true value.